# Implementing interface in different Subclasses with different entities using Java Generic T extends

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, interface, implements

I am trying to achieve something in Java using Generics, not sure if this is possible or not. If yes, please let me know the correct way.

This is the UML Diagram I have.
[image]

`User` is the base entity and `Customer` and `Employee` are both its subclass (or extending the User Class).

Now there is an interface called `UserManager`, and `CustomerManager` and `EmployeeManager` are both extending the interface. This is how my UserManager interface looks like:

```
public interface UserManager<T extends User> {

    List<T> getAllUsers();

    void createUser(T user);
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is both the implementing class `CustomerManager` and `EmployeeManager` should implement the methods but they should use their respective Entity instead of using the generic `T` in their implementations. Like:

CustomerManager methods should look like this:

```
@Override
public List<Customer> getAllUsers() {
   // SOME CODE
}

@Override
public void createUser(Customer user) {
   // SOME SODE
}
```

EmployeeManager methods should look like this:

```
@Override
public List<Employee> getAllUsers() {
   // SOME CODE
}
    
@Override
public void createUser(Employee user) {
   // SOME SODE
}
```

But I am not able to achieve this, it is working for the `getAllUsers` method but not for the `createUser` method, as you can see in the screenshot below. Can anyone help me identifying the mistake I am making here?

[image]

Comment: What about `public class EmployeeManager implements UserManager<Employee>`?

Comment: Should be: `public class CustomerManagerImpl implements UserManager<Customer> {`

Comment: Yes, it worked!!!